# x pages Question: calculate working day Error

Tags: xpages, lotus-formula

I try use computed field to calculate leave and working days. The error form show as below

[image: fault]

**script to count the working days**

```
var nDateStart = session.createDateTime(document1.getValue("StartDate")).toJavaDate();
var nDateEnd = session.createDateTime(document1.getValue("EndDate")).toJavaDate();

var syear = @Year(nDateStart)
var smth =  @Month(nDateStart)
var sday = @Day(nDateStart)
var startdate = @Date(syear,smth,sday)

var eyear = @Year(nDateEnd)
var emth =  @Month(nDateEnd)
var eday = @Day(nDateEnd)
var enddate = @Date(eyear,emth,eday)

var weekends = "1:7"; //assuming your weekend is Saturday and Sunday
var holidays = "@Date(2019;8;12):@Date(2019;12;25)"; // assuming your holiday is 12 August and 25th December
var formula = "@BusinessDays(" + startdate + ";" + enddate + ";" + weekends + ";" + holidays + ")";
return session.evaluate(formula);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date/time constants in Lotus formula language are enclosed in square brackets, which you can clearly see in the [documentation for @BusinessDays](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_BUSINESSDAYS_FUNCTION.html). Try this:

```
var formula = "@BusinessDays([" + startdate + "];[" + enddate + "];" + weekends + ";[" + holidays + "])";
return session.evaluate(formula);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate a valid formula before you can submit it to session.evaluate. The string you submit isn’t a valid formula. E.g the your parameter is just an unquoted string.
Remove the startdate and enddate and replace it with something like `”@Date(“+syear+”;”+smonth+”;”+”;”+sday+”)”` that should give you the formula you seek.

Comment: Don't copy my formula. The mobile editor messed up the quotes - hand type it!